# Google Login without webview in xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin

I'm developing an app google Login without webview 
I am Following this url (https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Auth/blob/portable-bait-and-switch/samples/Xamarin.Forms/references01project/Evolve16Labs/05-OAuth/Portable/MainPage.xaml.cs), Google Authentication is working in webview but I want authentication without webview

Answer (score 1):

This line

https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Auth/blob/portable-bait-and-switch/samples/Xamarin.Forms/references01project/Evolve16Labs/05-OAuth/Portable/MainPage.xaml.cs#L65

If set to true - user is using native UI - on Android CustomTabs and on iOS SFSafariViewController, so no embedded WebViews.

From that URL you are using - project references. Don't. I suggest use nuget references (believe me I'm Xamarin.Auth maintainer). Using project references implies Xamarin.Auth library solution is compiled (and before that packages restored).

Samples based on nuget references are extracted in the repo I keep for testing:

https://github.com/moljac/Xamarin.Auth.Samples.NugetReferences

Forms sample and Traditional "Providers" sample were tested by 20+ people and they work.

Due to the nature of stackoverflow and their moderation, someone will close or edit this question and answer soon, so go to Xamarin Chat (community slack team) and there are people that will help you out.

Comment: The Xamarin Forms project does not build. I get the error: cannot find symbol: android.support.v7.widget.CardView and several others. (all in the Samples.NativeUI.Android).

Comment: There are 2 Xamarin.Forms projects. ComicBook was tested so many times in last 2 weeks. Try updating all packages. And for help go to community slack https://xamarinchat.slack.com/messages/C4TD1NHPT/

Comment: Yes, the ComicBook is working, I just had to fix restoring Xamarin.Auth.XamarinForms in the PCL where the path was too long. Thanks.

Comment: @AH Xamarin.Forms support caused that the package setup is not trivial anymore and causes bunch of problems. General advice: bump everything to max version[s] and keep versions the same across projects. There is nice feature in VS - solution node +/ Manage Nuget packages for solution +/ Consolidate.

Comment: @moljac Sorry not clear to me if your project (google login for instance) can be fully tested in a development environment. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As I can see from the code, you are using OAuth2. In practise you can login without WebView, but you will need:

1. Ask user about their credentials (not very secure)
2. Hack google internal requests for authorization (schemes and redirections)
3. Somehow pass throw two phase verification (sms code)